# Calling count distinct on varchar field gets error

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am getting the below error while doing a `count distinct` on a `varchar` field

```
Function EXTRACT does not support VARCHAR(16777216) argument type
```

I am not able to figure out how to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Harsh, you are right. I also had a where clause on a data field and I was doing a YEAR(). I assumed that the date field is of timestamp data type. But someone defined it as VARCHAR and that was causing the issue

Answer (score 0):

> I am getting the below error while doing a count distinct on a varchar field

Please include a query that reproduces the issue for better answers. The limited description does not cover the context behind the error message.

> Function EXTRACT does not support VARCHAR(16777216) argument type

Going by the error message alone, it appears you've used more than just `COUNT` over your `VARCHAR` typed column (perhaps there are predicates with other functions in use).

Specifically, Snowflake's [`EXTRACT` function](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/extract.html) cannot be applied to a `VARCHAR` type, it only accepts a `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` type.

This is just a example/guess, but replace your `EXTRACT(year FROM column_name)` portion with `EXTRACT(year FROM TO_TIMESTAMP(column_name))` if the column can be parsed as a timestamp.